# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:

Tags: java, saucelabs, remotewebdriver

I am using Selenium with sauce labs and I am trying to run testng file from command line but it's throwing me the following error since 1 week. It was working fine before. Can some one please help me in solving this?

```
 Regression.whitecapQA.Regression1saucechrome.initialization  Time elapsed: 1.876 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: '5CD9270R9Z', ip: '10.232.40.247', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at Regression.whitecapQA.Regression1saucechrome.initialization(Regression1saucechrome.java:81)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at Regression.whitecapQA.Regression1saucechrome.initialization(Regression1saucechrome.java:81)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: add the related code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the trooubleshooting tips here to get your connection working in the Sauce Connect course:

https://training.saucelabs.com/codelabs/Module1-SauceConnect/index.html?index=..%2F..sauceconnect#3

If this doesn't work, file a support ticket by emailing support@saucelabs.com

Answer (score 0):

The relevant info here is:

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
> building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

Your code is unable to create a secure connection to the Sauce Labs servers.  Mostly, this happens because something in your network configuration is preventing it.

Since this used to work, I'd suggest that something outside of your *personal* control but still within your organization has changed.  Your network security tooling might be interfering with connections to Sauce Labs, your proxy details might have changed or the SSL certificate bundle used on your machine might be outdated.

I'd try the following:

1. Make sure your Java SDK is up to date
2. Make sure you've properly configured your IDE or environment.  If you need an explicit proxy to connect to the internet, make sure you've configured it.
3. Contact your network security team and ask whether you should be able to contact subdomains of Sauce Labs on port 80 and 443.